# Проблемы с установкой драйверов гостевой ОС Red Hat 7.4 VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, драйвер, redhat, rhel

Всем привет. Развернул на VirtualBox 5.2.6 ОС Red Hat Linux 7.4. Для удобства работы решил установить драйвера гостевой ОС, устанавливаются они конечно успешно, но после перезагрузки сервера происходит его благополучное зависание. Что делать ума не приложу, ибо раньше вообще с линуксами не работал. Можете посоветовать что сделать? Я конечно сделал предварительно снимок рабочей конфигурации, но хочется чтобы и размер экрана был адекватным и буфер обмена работал. И перед тем как ставить драйверы, я обновил систему всю, было каких-то 224 обновления, в том числе гнома и ядра. После этого все грузилось и работало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. расскажите подробнее как устанавливаете? вы установили kernel-headers, KERN_DIR, kernel-devel? – Senior Pomidor

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: расскажите подробнее как устанавливаете? вы установили kernel-headers, KERN_DIR, kernel-devel?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, стыдно признатья, но я не совсем понимаю этих тонкостей, устанаваливал как virtualbox велит, монтировал образ с гостевыми драйверами, далее в системе RHEL появилось предложение установить, все что на этом диске, я подтвердил и дождался окончания установки, более ничего не делал.

Answer (score 0):

для уствновки VirtualBox Guest Addition вам необходимо подготовить систему.

```
yum update
yum update kernel*
yum groupinstall "Development Tools" 
yum install epel-release dkms

У вас kernel-* должны быть той же версии, что и ядро 
yum -y install kernel-devel-`uname -r` \ 
     kernel-headers-`uname -r` \
     kernel-debug-devel-`uname -r` \ 
     gcc gcc-c++ bzip2 
echo "export KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/\`uname -r\`" >> /etc/bashrc
```

перезагрузка системы.

Подключаете образ VirtualBox Guest Addition

```
mkdir /mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions
sh /mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
reboot
```